Since my last update 24.04.01 Berlin timezone is only partly available
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata shows Berlin.
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Berlin
[sudo] Passwort für david: 
Failed to set time zone: Invalid or not installed time zone 'Europe/Berlin'



That looks like a bug or some issues on your setup (e.g. corrupted files etc). Please file a bug: ubuntu-bug tzdata
